# How to read the jsonstream from uiwebview?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiwebview, uiwebviewdelegate

When the server gives the response JSON the `webviewdidfinishload` method is not get called and I did'nt know how to read this steam from the server. For reference see screenshot:

[http://www.flickr.com/photos/97186141@N05/9388886673/](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IMjI7.jpg)

Comment: Don't expect an answer for such a vague question.

Comment: ok @A-Live.Let me explain, just imagine that you are entering a url in your browser on that moment a popup box appears on your browser asking you to save the file or cancel it(see the above mentioned link for clarity.It is a screen shot taken from firefox). my question is how to read the content of the file appeared in the browser using uiwebview.when I tried it using uiwebview the webview didfinishload is not called and I don't know how to capture that event and read.